# Voltage subtractor using MOSFET

Tags: voltage, voltage-measurement, current-limiting

I am new to this site and maybe I won't ask a good question but anyway.

I have come up with a voltage subtractor using two MOSFETs and a voltage divider well sort of.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj1xhC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Vout = VCC - VM2

If Vu < Vtm2 -> Vout = 0

If Vu > Vtm2 and Vd < Vtm1 since R1 >> Rm2 -> Vout = VCC

If Vu > Vtm2 and Vd > Vtm1 since Rm1 || R1 and Rm1 << R1 the resistance of the loop is Rm1.

The resistance Rm1 depends on gate voltage (Vd) as well as Rm2 depends on gate voltage (Vu).

We want when Vd = Vu Vout to be 0 (substractor Vu-Vd). However if M1 is M2 then when Vd = Vu -> Rm1 = Rm2 -> Vout = VCC/2.

So the rate at which resistance changes according to gate voltage in the M1 must be bigger than M2 so that Rm1 << Rm2 << R1 -> Vout  = 0.

MSF1's resistance changes more rapidly with increase in gate voltage than MSF2.

However currents using MOSFETs are very big some amps while I would like this to work for mA. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. The circuit diagram is quite blurry. [Guidelines for a good photo of a schematic](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7232/238590). you can also use the schematic editor to add a good diagram.

Comment: "*MSF1's resistance changes more rapidly with increase in gate voltage than MSF2.*" Why is this restriction necessary ? Can you write down the equations for \$V_{out}\$ as a function of the input voltage ? "*However currents using MOSFETs are very big some Amps*" Where does this restriction come from ?

Comment: AJN the VI curve of VI of a MOSFET ( VG and ID) is on amps.

Comment: What is VM2 meant to be? Ditto Rm1 and Rm2?

Comment: Vm2 is the voltage drop on M2 mosfet , Rm1 and Rm2 are the resistances of M1 and M2 mosfets.

Comment: Tip: Stack Exchange supports HTML entities such as `&deg;`, `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&pm;` (+/-), `&ge;` (>=), etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` (superscript) and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts but they don't render in the comments.

Comment: `If Vu > Vtm2 and Vd < Vtm1 -> Vout = VCC`. This might not be true if \$V_{tm2}\$ stands for the threshold voltage of M2. \$V_u > V_o + V_{tm2}\$ for M2 to get turned ON. [Threshold voltage is measured with respect to source voltage of the same MOSFET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#Modes_of_operation). There may be problems in the other equations also. You can try simulating this circuit and ensure that it works. The diagram editor you used to create the diagram can do simulations.

Comment: Hmm ur correct.But if Vd <Vtm1 then it is true.